# Parse JSON using only org.JSON

Tags: java, json

I have been struggling to accomplish something which I thought would be simple with org.json. I receive some JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "startDate": "2016-08-22T19:07:20.000Z",
    "endDate": "2016-08-23T19:07:20.000Z",
    "products": [{
        "name": "&lt;Device Level Product&gt;",
        "deviceIdSensorIdArr": [{
            "deviceId": 13124,
            "sensorId": null
        }],
        "dataProductId": 1,
        "dataProductFormatId": 2,
        "searchTypeId": 5,
        "searchNodeId": 115,
        "siteDeviceId": null,
        "resourceTypeId": 1500,
        "resourceId": 183,
        "parameter": {
            "35": "1",
            "38": "1",
            "40": ["41", "0"]
        }
    }, {
        "name": "Air Temperature",
        "deviceIdSensorIdArr": [{
            "deviceId": 13124,
            "sensorId": 9044
        }],
        "dataProductId": 1,
        "dataProductFormatId": 2,
        "searchTypeId": 5,
        "searchNodeId": 115,
        "siteDeviceId": null,
        "resourceTypeId": 1501,
        "resourceId": 5235,
        "parameter": {
            "35": "1",
            "38": "1",
            "40": ["41", "0"]
        }
    }]
}
```

I need to get the "deviceId" value for each object in the "products" array. Retrieving the entries in the object such as "name" or "searchNodeId" is easy but I'm struggling to get "deviceId" because it is a second layer down. The code below is what I have thus far. I can easily get the the first layer of values such as name but not deviceId. I'm sure there is a simpler way with other libraries but I am only allowed to use org.JSON and am using it for the first time.

```
        values = wp.getFormParameters("parameters");
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(values);
        JSONArray products = obj.getJSONArray("products");
        for(int i = 0; i < products.length(); ++i){
            String name = products.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
            JSONObject deviceIdStr = products.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("deviceIdSensorIdArr");
            String deviceId = deviceIdStr.getString("deviceId");
        }
```

**EDIT**

To clairfy the point of the question, I can't figure out how to use org.JSON functions to get into the second layer of the JSON string. I could write a method to parse out deviceId myself but there has to be a way of doing it with org.JSON that I haven't yet figure out.

Comment: What are you confused about? Where are you blocked? Do you understand the [JSON format](http://json.org/)?

Comment: Yeah I understand JSON. I can get the complex string for the "deviceIdSensorIdArr" variable but then not sure how to use org.JSON to further parse it. I mean. I could brute force parse but there has to a built in way of extracting sub components with org.JSON that I can't figure out.

Comment: There is not. If you need a JSON string that is inside a JSON object, that is inside a JSON array, that is inside a JSON object, then you need to parse it that way.

Comment: what kind of built in way are you expecting? Like just give the key name and library should give you the value.

Comment: If you're willing to explore more sophisticated alternatives to the org.json library, look at [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) and its [tree model](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/08/entry_460.html), and/or [JsonPath](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this-

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(content);
    JSONArray products = obj.getJSONArray("products");
    for(int i = 0; i < products.length(); ++i){
        String name = products.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
        JSONArray array = products.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("deviceIdSensorIdArr");
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length(); j++) {
            String string = array.getJSONObject(j).getString("deviceId");
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
```

Output was

13124

13124